# Moving data from local directory to AWS

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm very new to R so be gentle. I've been tasked to make some amendments to a pre-existing project.

I have some code:

```
#SHINY_ROOT <- getwd()
#ARCHIVE_FILEPATH  <- file.path(SHINY_ROOT, 'Data', 'archived_pqs.csv')
```

I want to move 'archived_pqs.csv' into S3 (Amazon Web Services), preferably while making as few changes to the rest of the code as possible.

My first thought was that I could do this:

```
ARCHIVE_FILEPATH  <- s3tools::s3_path_to_full_df("alpha-pq-tool-data/Data/archived_pqs.csv")
```

Where 'alpha-pq-tool-data' is the S3 bucket.

I've tested this and it does indeed pull in the dataframe:

```
df <-s3tools::s3_path_to_full_df("alpha-pq-tool-data/Data/archived_pqs.csv")
```

The issue is that when I run other functions that go as follows:

```
if(file.exists(ARCHIVE_FILEPATH)) {
date        <- last_answer_date()}
```

I get this error:

```
Error in file.exists(ARCHIVE_FILEPATH) : invalid 'file' argument
Called from: file.exists(ARCHIVE_FILEPATH)
```

Is there any easy way of doing this while making minimal changes? Can I no longer use file.exists function because the data is in S3?

Comment: `file.exists()` can only be used to test local file systems (or things that behave like local filesystems). `s3tools` has a `s3_file_exists()` function which should be used to test for the existence of files in S3 buckets.

Comment: Do you have any documentation around the 's3_file_exists' function? I've googled it but I couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: Hrm. It seems to be an internal-only function in the `s3tools` package: https://github.com/moj-analytical-services/s3tools/blob/b8b01fab40512073d7e380592367265c66f29032/R/utils.R#L16-L20 so you can call it with `s3tools:::s3_file_exists()`

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at that